# How to display a 3D array initialized in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning *Excel VBA Programming for Dummies*, 3rd Edition.
There's an example which uses nested For-Next loops to initialize a three-dimensional array with the value of 100.

I want to see this sub procedure's result.

```
Sub NestedLoops()
    Dim MyArray(10, 10, 10)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            For k = 1 To 10
                MyArray(i, j, k) = 100
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried using a MsgBox to display MyArray, but it says *Type mismatch*. Is there a way to show the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a couple of things.

1. Excel usually shows 2D data (row & col are the same as height and width or X and Y on a graph).  You have 3D data.
2. If you insist on forcing Excel to show the data, then you would need to use worksheets as the 3rd dimension.  So you would create a sheet for each I and on that sheet, you would fill in each cell with j and k (where j was a row and k was a column).  If you do this right, you should end up with 10 sheets each with 100 in every cell from a1 to j10.

As it appears you are taking a class, I will leave it to you to figure out how to write the data out to the sheets.